# Postfix IMAP/POP3 migration with UIDL preservation

Tags: rsync, migration, imap, pop3

I have two Centos servers:

The old one (server1) with Postfix and Courier as mail service, using roundcube and atmail (free) for IMAP webclient and POP3 for desktop clients too.

The new one (server2) with the same Postfix and Courier service, roundcube and atmail (free).

I want to migrate all our client's emails from server1 to server2, with all their **IMAP folders**, and **preventing duplicates** for POP3 desktop clients (**UIDL preservation**).

How can I do this?

Also, I tried with imapsync/rsync, but the desktop clients duplicates old emails.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried follow instructions Migrating from any IMAP/POP3 server to Dovecot via dsync? http://wiki2.dovecot.org/Migration/Dsync

Comment: Welcome to Serverfault!  It would be very helpful if you could add some detail from the link to your answer.  That way, if this link does ever break this answer can continue to provide some value.

Comment: The page linked to is 95% useful, but is missing one vital element: it does not say where to place the migration config! It explains how to setup the config file to do an IMAP or POP migration from the old server, but not what/where to edit. Do you have any links with that information?